# Error parsing Xml Rss feed in android

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, logcat

hi there i'm newbie in android development and i'm following a tutrial but i got an errors so i need help , i'm trying to make a project to get rss feed from apple store" top 10 apps" and parsing it into android studio project and show it in listview  ..
here's the error log

```
> 09-30 18:04:35.196    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6ae73bc
> time:91550625
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.331    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object
> reference
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at
> com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader.ParseApplications.process(ParseApplications.java:37)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at
> com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> W/System.err﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
> 
> 09-30 18:04:36.426    1969-1969/com.katarina.ahmed.top10appdownloader
> D/Main activity﹕ Error Parsing file
```

the code for main is :

```
PAckage com.com.katarina.top10appdownloader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnParse;
    ListView listApps;
    String XmlData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnParse=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnParse);
        listApps=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listApps);
        btnParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseApplications parse = new ParseApplications(XmlData);

                boolean operationStatus=parse.process();

                if(operationStatus)
                {
                    ArrayList<Application> allApps=parse.getApplications();
                    ArrayAdapter<Application> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Application>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,allApps);
                    listApps.setVisibility(listApps.VISIBLE);
                    listApps.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Main activity","Error Parsing file");
                }

            }
        });
        new DownloadData().execute("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        String myXmlData;
        protected String doInBackground(String...urls)
        {
            try {
                myXmlData=downloadXML(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                return " unable to download XML file ";
            }
            return "";
        }
        protected void onpostexecute(String result) {
            Log.d("OnPostExecute", myXmlData);
            XmlData=myXmlData;
        }
        private String downloadXML (String theUrl) throws IOException
        {
            int BUFFER_SIZE=2000;
            InputStream is =null;
            String xmlContents ="";
            try{
                URL url=new URL(theUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                int response=conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("Downloadxml","The REsponse returned is: "+response);
                is=conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(is);
                int charRead;
                char[] inputBuffer=new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                try {
                    while ((charRead=isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
                    {
                        String readString=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                        xmlContents+=readString;
                        inputBuffer=new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    }
                    return xmlContents;

                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return  null;
                }

            } finally {
                if (is!=null)
                    is.close();
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

the parsing class :

```
package com.katarina.top10appdownloader;

import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ParseApplications {
    private String data;
    private ArrayList<Application> applications;

    public ParseApplications(String XmlData) {
        data = XmlData;
        applications = new ArrayList<Application>();

    }

    public ArrayList<Application> getApplications() {
        return applications;
    }

    public boolean process() {
        boolean operationstatus = true;

        Application currentRecord = null;
        boolean inEntry = false;
        String textValue = "";
        try {

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(this.data));
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = xpp.getName();

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
                        inEntry = true;
                        currentRecord = new Application();
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    textValue = xpp.getText();
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (inEntry) {
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
                            applications.add(currentRecord);
                            inEntry = false;
                        }
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                            currentRecord.setName(textValue);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("atrist")) {
                            currentRecord.setArtist(textValue);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("releaseDate")) {
                            currentRecord.setReleaseDate(textValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
                eventType=xpp.next();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            operationstatus = false;
        }
        for(Application app:applications)
        {
            Log.d("LOG","*****************");
            Log.d("LOG",app.getName());
            Log.d("LOG",app.getArtist());
            Log.d("LOG",app.getReleaseDate());
        }
        return operationstatus;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance ..

Comment: Looks like its crashin on 'xpp.setInput(new StringReader(this.data));' have you verified that data is not null?

Comment: yea i think i made it in
 public ParseApplications(String XmlData) {
        data = XmlData;
        applications = new ArrayList<Application>();

    }

Comment: yes but the value you pass through could be coming in as null. There are no null checks on the button, so it might not have completed the http task by the time you press it, assuming that the request is valid ofc.